# How to save remote notification data into Core Data(Database) from NotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, notifications, serviceextension

I have implemented **NotificationServiceExtension** in my target application, and it is working fine.

- Created AppgroupID

  ```
   lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {

       var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
       let options = [
           NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
           ]

       let oldStoreUrl = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
       let directory: NSURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: AppGroupID)! as NSURL
       let newStoreUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")!

       var targetUrl : URL? = nil
       var needMigrate = false
       var needDeleteOld = false


       if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: oldStoreUrl.path){
          needMigrate = true
          targetUrl = oldStoreUrl
       }
       if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: newStoreUrl.path){
          needMigrate = false
          targetUrl = newStoreUrl

          if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: oldStoreUrl.path){
              needDeleteOld = true
          }
       }
       if targetUrl == nil {
          targetUrl = newStoreUrl
       }

       if needMigrate {
          do {
              try coordinator?.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: targetUrl!, options: options) 
              if let store = coordinator?.persistentStore(for: targetUrl!) {
                  do {
                      try coordinator?.migratePersistentStore(store, to: newStoreUrl, options: options, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)

                  } catch let error {
                      print("migrate failed with error : \(error)")
                  }
              }
          } catch let error {
              //CrashlyticsHelper.reportCrash(err: error as NSError, strMethodName: "migrateStore")
              print(error)
          }
      }

      if needDeleteOld {
          self.deleteDocumentAtUrl(url: oldStoreUrl)
          self.deleteDocumentAtUrl(url: self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite-shm"))
          self.deleteDocumentAtUrl(url: self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite-wal"))
      }

      do {
          try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: targetUrl, options: options)
      } catch var error as NSError {
          coordinator = nil
          NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
          abort()
      } catch {
          fatalError()
      }
      return coordinator

  }() 

    **EDIT:**

  lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {

  let urls = Foundation.FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
  return urls[urls.count-1]}()

  override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

   self.contentHandler = contentHandler
   bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? 
   UNMutableNotificationContent)

  if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
      // Modify the notification content here...
      print("Mutable Data %@",bestAttemptContent)
      bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title)"
      //bestAttemptContent.title = "Notification"

       let apnsDic = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
          // NotificationManager.sharedInstance.handlePushNotification(byUserTapped: true, content: apnsDic)
          contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)

  } }

    // Storing APNS dictionary into database from extension

    func handlePushNotification(byUserTapped : Bool,content : NSDictionary) {

   let moduelDataDic = content.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary

  let entity2 =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "TextMessage",
                                            in: CoreDataStorage.sharedInstance.mainQueueCtxt!)

  let textMsg = NSManagedObject(entity: entity2!,
                                insertInto: CoreDataStorage.sharedInstance.mainQueueCtxt) as? TextMessage

  let trimmedMessage = (moduelDataDic.object(forKey: "msgbody")! as AnyObject).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

  textMsg?.message = trimmedMessage
  msgInfo?.toText = textMsg
  rosterInfo.time = composeMsgDate as Date
  rosterInfo.addToToMessageInfo(NSSet(object: msgInfo!))

  DispatchQueue.main.async {

      let context = CoreDataStorage.sharedInstance.mainQueueCtxt
      if let moc = context {
          if moc.hasChanges {
              do {
                  try moc.save()
              } catch {
                  let nserror = error as NSError
                  print("Could not save In NotficationManager \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
              }
          }
      }

  } }
  ```

  In application background mode here I am fetching data which are stored in above method of NotificationServiceExtension and in my result i can get  data from manageObject table (messageInfo) but no any data into relationship "let setArray = rosterInfo?.toMessageInfo"

  ```
  let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "messageID == %@", 
  moduelDataDic.object(forKey: "message_id")! as! CVarArg)

  let messageInfoAry = 
  self.fetchMessagesFromCoreDataWithPredicate(resultPredicate: 
  resultPredicate, sortDescriptorKey: "time", isAscending: true, 
  fetchLimit: false, managedContext: self.getManageObjectContext())
  if messageInfoAry.count > 0 {

  let rosterInfo = (messageInfoAry[0] as! MessageInfo).toRoster
  let msgInfo = messageInfoAry[0] as! MessageInfo

  // Here i don't see msgInfo in this relationship but after relaunching my application i can able to see that same object

  let setArray = rosterInfo?.toMessageInfo
  ```

  Any help from anyone?

Comment: Whatexactly happens "i can see that data only weird behaviour "?

Comment: @shallowThought : In my case i can able to save data when app into killed mode but when in background mode technically first my extension delegate called where i storing remote notification data into core-data after that my application remote notification delegate called here i am trying to fetch that same data which i stored from extension but can't see. and after relaunching app i can see that same data.

Comment: I did not understand this, sorry.

Comment: You posted the code for your persistentStoreCoordinator. would you post the code for your notification save as well please?

Comment: Try checking the core data model location in simulator (You can take a look at the simulator where you have permissions to everything). I think the Notification extension have different app directory than the actual app due to being it new separate bundle as all extensions.

Comment: have you added this delegation function in the AppDelegate class -- func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
    } --

Comment: @DominikBucher : Can you please check i have updated code.

Comment: Hmm I still don't see the `applicationDocumentsDirectory` property (The value of this) so I can tell you where is the location...

Comment: @DominikBucher : check now.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the following code to your `AppDelegate` class and test it.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(.newData)
    performSelector(inBackground: #selector(saveNewNotificationInBackground(userInfo:)), with: userInfo)
}

@objc func saveNewNotificationInBackground(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void {
    //save notification using core data
}
```

Comment: Jayachandra A: Inverse relationship not working when my application into background mode.
rosterInfo.addToToMessageInfo(NSSet(object: msgInfo!)) here i am storing data in one to many relationship form !